# i am not getting displayed the post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

in this i have put request the api its being consoled i want to show it on my screen like crud can anyone help me with it i have used axios.put i think i havnt added the code plaese help me.please help me with this i am a beginner in react.
my api link [restapi]
i am posting my code bekow please go through it:

```
import axios from "axios";
import react, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import './App.css'

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setsearchTerm] = useState("");

  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [body, setBody] = useState('');
  const postData =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1",{
    title,
    body
   } ).then(res=>console.log('posting',res))
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1").then((res) => {
      setUsers(res.data);
      
    });
  }, []);

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div className="flex">
     <input
      onChange={(e) => {
        setsearchTerm(e.target.value);
      } }
      type="text"
      placeholder="search"
      className="form-control"
      style={{
        width: "80%",
        borderRadius: "30px 0  30px",
        justifyContent: "center",
        marginLeft: "100px",
      }} />
      <br/>
      <br/>
       <form>
         <label>first_name</label>
         <input value={title} onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}/>
         <label>email</label>
         <input value={body} onChange={(e)=>setBody(e.target.value)}/>
         <button onClick={postData}>post</button>
      {users?.data?.filter((val) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return val;
              } else if (val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                return val;
              }

            }).map((datas) => (
      <div key={datas.id}>
      <p>
        <strong>{datas.first_name}</strong>
      </p>
      <p>{datas.email}</p>
      <img key={datas.avatar} src={datas.avatar} />
    </div>
      ))}
      </form>
      </div>      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I hope that's how you wanted it to work.

Post request to api - `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1` return data in different form than the api - `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1`. So in order to add and show the entered data in the users list, you have to customized the data before adding it to the `users` useState. Like this:

```
    setUsers([
          ...users,
          {
            id: res.data.id,
            first_name: res.data.title,
            email: res.data.body,
            avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg",
          },
        ]);
```

**Note -** I have used a random image while adding the entered data to the users list. As no avatar was being returned from the api.

**Full working code:**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import react, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setsearchTerm] = useState("");

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const postData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1", {
        title,
        body,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setUsers([
          ...users,
          {
            id: res.data.id,
            first_name: res.data.title,
            email: res.data.body,
            avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg",
          },
        ]);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1").then((res) => {
      setUsers(res.data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="flex">
        <input
          onChange={(e) => {
            setsearchTerm(e.target.value);
          }}
          type="text"
          placeholder="search"
          className="form-control"
          style={{
            width: "80%",
            borderRadius: "30px 0  30px",
            justifyContent: "center",
            marginLeft: "100px",
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <form>
          <label>first_name</label>
          <input value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
          <label>email</label>
          <input value={body} onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)} />
          <button onClick={postData}>post</button>
          {users
            .filter((val) => {
              if (searchTerm === "") {
                return val;
              } else if (
                val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return val;
              }
            })
            .map((datas) => (
              <div key={datas.id}>
                <p>
                  <strong>{datas.first_name}</strong>
                </p>
                <p>{datas.email}</p>
                <img key={datas.avatar} src={datas.avatar} />
              </div>
            ))}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: sir how can i delete the api